# import json without caching the file (next.js or node.js)

Tags: json, api, caching, import, next.js

I built an api with next.js.
I use a JSON file as a data source. I import it as a module. But if the content of the JSON changes, it still shows the first content, the same, when i started the server.

Is there a way to avoid caching JSON with import?

I need to get the JSON content, but also the updates in the JSON file, without restarting my api.

Answer (score 1):

If your Server returns the JSON files with a specific File-Extension like .json you could try to turn off the caching for those file-types:

[Here is an example for ngnix-servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344766/nginx-disable-cache-in-specific-folder-for-a-specific-file-type)

[Here is an example for apache-servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316240/turn-off-cache-for-specific-file-with-apache)

Another possibility is to load the JSON via Javascript where you add some random parameter to the Query-Params of the URL
[Here is the Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897849/load-external-script-without-cache-using-javascript)